# Adding a datepicker in relativel ayout crashes with nullpointer exception

Tags: android, datepicker, android-studio

I am using Android Studio for designing layouts.

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- I want to add DatePicker here -->



    <GridView

        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="@integer/magic_square_cols"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"

        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

But as soon as I drag and drop or add `DatePicker` . The UI crashes with rendering problems and gives a NullPointerException which I have pasted here:

http://uthcode.codepad.org/UQeYO5Qn

Is there any limitation in the layout+view that I am encountering?

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: Assume that Activity is Empty. It crashes at the design (The code is pasted above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62239 and the fix should be released soon.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that it was  bug with Studio Preview Renderer only and on phone, it could work well.